# InvalidValueError: setCenter: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: not an Object

Tags: javascript, google-maps, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I am trying to get circle on a map according to the place I input in a textbox. I am getting the place but not the circle. I debugged it and it always goes to the else part which should show an error dialog box. But I am not getting the dialog box also. I checked in the console and I am getting the error as :

> InvalidValueError: setCenter: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: not an
>   Object

**CODE:**

```
<!DOCTYPE  link href="https://maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Geolocation and Google Maps API</title>
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>

        function writeAddressName()
        {
            var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            var add = document.getElementById('address').value;
            var myOptions =
            {
                zoom: 9,
                center: add,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var mapObject = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
            geocoder.geocode(
            {
                'address': add
            },

            function (results, status)
            {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
                {
                    var circle = new google.maps.Circle(
                    {
                        center: mapObject.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location),
                        radius: /*position.coords.accuracy*/16090 * 2,
                        map: mapObject,
                        fillColor: '#0000FF',
                        fillOpacity: 0.5,
                        strokeColor: '#0000FF',
                        strokeOpacity: 1.0
                    });
                    mapObject.fitBounds(circle.getBounds());

                    mapObject.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                    var hint = new google.maps.Marker(
                    {
                        mapObject: mapObject,
                        position: results[0].geometry.location
                    });
                }    
                else
                {
                    alert('This code is not successful ' + status);
                }
            });
        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', writeAddressName);
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
      #map 
      {
        height: 450px;
        border: 5px solid #5E5454;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Basic example</h1>
      <div id="map"></div>
      <div id="panel">
                Enter your region:
                    <input id="address" type="textbox">
                <input type="button" value="Search" onclick="writeAddressName()">
            </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have tried to set center by using means but none of it is working. Any kind of help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the value of `results[0].geometry.location`, because [it either needs to be an instance of a latlang class, or an object with lat/lng key/value pairs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting your Circle's center as

```
center: mapObject.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location)
```

but the `.setCenter` method of `mapObject` doesn't return a `LatLng` object, so `center:` is undefined.

Use the location directly:

```
center: results[0].geometry.location
```